# Get the number of features displayed on a map after a filter (with featuresIn)

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

First of all, I'm aware that `querySourceFeatures` could fix that. But unfortunately the new version is effective with all types but not with symbols, which I'm using. So I'm still coding under version 0.14.x.

That said, I filter my map with the `setFilter` function and I need to catch back the number of features displayed once the filter is done.
I thought about transform the  whole world (-90,-180,90,180) map coordinates into pixels and then pass it into a `featuresIn` function.

With fiddle below,  featuresIn returns nothing [**EDIT** : that was due to not setting `interacive : true`, now it's done but issue is still here]. Do you have any idea how to get the number of features displayed on my map?

**EDIT** : Please find my jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/y7hoa0gy/7/

Comment: Could you provide a functional demo of your code? There isn't enough information here to confidently diagnose your problem. Thanks!

Comment: @LucasWojciechowski Demo added. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No features are being returned from `featuresIn` because you did not set `"interactive": true` on the "route" layer, as specified in the [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/d07685da62db7e45ad35715ac72315fa466d0deb/js/ui/map.js#L339) (but no longer on our official docs page because we have changed this API).

---

`/*Now I want to know how many features are still displayed after that filter
    My thought was to get the bbox of the whole map (-180,-90,180,90) and make a featuresIn of that bbox.*/`

More fundamentally, this approach will not work. `featuresIn` only returns features in the current viewport. It does not return all features.

Comment: Outch yes my bad, it couldn't work. Ok I understand the current viewport, but it admits a bbox as parameter, so I thought it could render the features in the bbox given, what is it about then?
I've tried another way by jumpTo the center of the map before calling featuresIn but the features filtered are rendered too late sometimes .. Is there a way to catch the event for knowing when the features are rendered after a setFilter? Sorry for insisting but I really need that number :) https://jsfiddle.net/rbe56vz7/1/

Comment: Ok I fixed my problem by filter the json in parallel. Thanks